# Calculate sum of child entities of list parent enities

Tags: c#, linq

I have to calculate the total fee of services that have child services.
The way to calculate sum of Entities in linq is:

```
double totalcost = db.Services.Sum(s=>s.cost);
```

But how could i calculate to total fee of list services such as:

```
double totalfee=db.services.childservices.sum(s=>s.fee);
```

or something like that?
I dont want to use loop as while cause it's take a long time when i have to calculate 1000 services at a time!

Comment: Can you tell me the join in my scene? i use DMBL with db is the datacontext. db.Services.Join(???childservice)

Comment: Table descirption and accepted output specify

Comment: my Table: Service {serviceID,serviceName,Cost}, ChildServices{childserviceID,childserviceName,serviceID,Fee}, i have a list of Services an must calculate total Fee of ChildService of that Services.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your model is something like the following:

```
public class Service
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public double Cost { get; set; }
  public ICollection<ChildService> ChildServices { get; set; }
}

public class ChildService
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public double Fee { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this to calculate the total fee over all services:

```
double? totalFee = db.Services.Sum(service => service.ChildServices.Sum(child => (double?)child.Fee));
```

The `double?` are there to guard againt the case when there's nothing to sum in the database. In that case the result will be `null`.

If you want a list of total fees over all service, you can:

```
List<double?> totalFees = db.Services.Select(service => service.ChildServices.Sum(child => (double?)child.Fee)).ToList();
```

If you want zeros instead of `null`, just replace the above queries with:

```
double totalFee = db.Services.Sum(service => service.ChildServices.Sum(child => (double?)child.Fee)) ?? 0;
List<double> totalFees = db.Services.Select(service => service.ChildServices.Sum(child => (double?)child.Fee) ?? 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. But i need to calculate a list of Services, for Ex 1000 services.

Comment: The above query calculates the sum of child service fees of all the services in the database, and then sum all those sums up as `totalFee`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover more cases. Please see if it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = services.SelectMany(q => q.ChildServices).Distinct().Sum(p => p.Fee);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var childFeeSum=from parentService in db.Services select new { Fee=parentService.Sum(parent=>parent.ChildServices.Sum(f=>f.Fee))};
```